# Error return empty arraylist from gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I try to compare two arraylist and check the differences between the two. the first arraylist I get from Gridview1 that was created manually, and the second arraylist I get by retrieving some data from database.

Here is my code so far:

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim strCheck As String = txtQuery.Text
    Dim arrayList1 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim arrayList2 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
    Dim arrayList3 As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    If strCheck.IndexOf("SELECT", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("Customer ID", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("SUM", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("Price ($)", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("Total Prices", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("tbl_product", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 And
        strCheck.IndexOf("GROUP BY", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
        For a = 0 To Gridview2.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
            For b = 0 To Gridview2.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                arrayList1.Add(Gridview2.Rows(a).Cells(b).Text)
                'TarrayList1.Add(arrayList1.Sort())
                arrayList1.Sort()
            Next
        Next

        For c = 0 To GridView3.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
            For d = 0 To GridView3.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                arrayList2.Add(GridView3.Rows(c).Cells(d).Text)
                arrayList2.Sort()
            Next
        Next

        For Each listElement As String In arrayList1
            If Not arrayList2.Contains(listElement) Then
                arrayList3.Add(listElement)
            End If
        Next

        For Each listElement As String In arrayList2
            If Not arrayList1.Contains(listElement) Then
                arrayList3.Add(listElement)
            End If
        Next

        Dim dtNew As DataTable = New DataTable()
        dtNew.Columns.Add("Array")
        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To arrayList3.Count - 1 Step 1
            dtNew.Rows.Add()
            dtNew.Rows(j)("Array") = arrayList3(j).ToString()
        Next
        GridView4.DataSource = dtNew
        GridView4.DataBind()

        If GridView4.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("TRUE")
        Else
            MsgBox("FALSE")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("False")
    End If
End Sub
```

>
The code will compare arraylist1 and arraylist2, if there is any differences then it will be added to arraylist3.

The error result is in 
`arrayList2`
I don't why when I check the arraylist2 it returns an empty arraylist.

Do you have any suggestion why the code give such error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint and see why the array isn't being populated?

Comment: Yes, already and there is no error. I tried to display the arrayList2 instead of arrayList3 on Gridview4 on the code above, and it doesn't display anything.